# Strange D state process, likely stuck at page fault handler?

Tags: linux-kernel

I have a D state process, but it doesn't seem to be in the middle of any syscall. It is a CPU intensive process (tensorflow), and it hanged while another CPU intensive process (bazel) was running. Here are some diagnose info (after `cd /proc/4088`):

```
➜  4088 uname -a
Linux  4.4.0-62-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 18 14:10:15 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
➜  4088 sudo cat status
Name:   python3
State:  D (disk sleep)
(output omitted)
```

```
➜  4088 sudo cat syscall
-1 0x7ffd69619900 0x7f0bec881390
```

```
➜  4088 cat wchan
call_rwsem_down_read_failed%
```

```
➜  4088 sudo cat stack
[] call_rwsem_down_read_failed+0x14/0x30
[] __do_page_fault+0x375/0x400
[] do_page_fault+0x22/0x30
[] page_fault+0x28/0x30
[] 0xffffffffffffffff
```

I have also verified that context switch count does not increase. There is <del>no</del> one suspicious entry in dmesg:

```
[69396.390301] BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at ffffea020f767740
[69396.390306] IP: [] mem_cgroup_try_charge+0x2f/0x1e0
[69396.390308] PGD 25edee067 PUD 0 
[69396.390310] Oops: 0000 [#3] SMP 
[69396.390338] Modules linked in: dm_snapshot drbg ansi_cprng ctr ccm pci_stub vboxpci(OE) vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) binfmt_misc intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel uvcvideo kvm snd_hda_codec_hdmi videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops arc4 videobuf2_v4l2 irqbypass videobuf2_core v4l2_common snd_hda_codec_realtek videodev snd_hda_codec_generic crct10dif_pclmul media crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel snd_hda_intel aesni_intel snd_hda_codec aes_x86_64 lrw ath9k snd_hda_core nvidia_uvm(POE) gf128mul snd_hwdep glue_helper ath9k_common ablk_helper ath9k_hw cryptd snd_pcm ath snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event mac80211 input_leds joydev snd_rawmidi serio_raw snd_seq cfg80211 snd_seq_device snd_timer rtsx_pci_ms memstick snd mei_me soundcore shpchp mei lpc_ich wmi mac_hid
[69396.390353]  nfsd auth_rpcgss nfs_acl lockd grace sunrpc parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 dm_thin_pool dm_persistent_data dm_bio_prison dm_bufio libcrc32c hid_generic usbhid hid psmouse rtsx_pci_sdmmc i915 nvidia_drm(POE) nvidia_modeset(POE) i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops nvidia(POE) drm ahci alx libahci rtsx_pci mdio video fjes
[69396.390356] CPU: 4 PID: 4176 Comm: python3 Tainted: P      D    OE   4.4.0-62-generic #83-Ubuntu
[69396.390357] Hardware name: Hasee QTC6/HM76, BIOS SR161 02/04/2013
[69396.390358] task: ffff8801d987d400 ti: ffff8801c4bd8000 task.ti: ffff8801c4bd8000
[69396.390362] RIP: 0010:[]  [] mem_cgroup_try_charge+0x2f/0x1e0
[69396.390363] RSP: 0000:ffff8801c4bdbdd0  EFLAGS: 00010246
[69396.390364] RAX: 017fffc000000000 RBX: ffffea0006565140 RCX: ffff8801c4bdbe68
[69396.390365] RDX: 00000000024000c0 RSI: ffff8801d5401400 RDI: ffffea0006565140
[69396.390365] RBP: ffff8801c4bdbe00 R08: ffffffff81cd2dc4 R09: ffffffff81cd2db3
[69396.390366] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: ffffffff81cd2da2 R12: ffffea020f767740
[69396.390367] R13: ffff8801c4bdbe68 R14: 00000000024000c0 R15: ffff8801d5401400
[69396.390369] FS:  00007f0b9d431700(0000) GS:ffff88025f300000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[69396.390370] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[69396.390371] CR2: ffffea020f767740 CR3: 000000007c070000 CR4: 00000000001406e0
[69396.390371] Stack:
[69396.390373]  0000000000000000 ffffea0006565140 ffff88020b726640 0000000000000000
[69396.390375]  ffff88020cf7b4d8 00007f0b53600008 ffff8801c4bdbed0 ffffffff811c1e32
[69396.390377]  0000000000000000 0000000000000000 00007f0b9d42fe00 0000000000000001
[69396.390377] Call Trace:
[69396.390382]  [] handle_mm_fault+0x14b2/0x1820
[69396.390386]  [] ? do_futex+0x107/0x540
[69396.390389]  [] ? blk_finish_plug+0x2c/0x40
[69396.390393]  [] ? SyS_madvise+0x48d/0x7d0
[69396.390395]  [] ? __schedule+0x3b6/0xa30
[69396.390398]  [] __do_page_fault+0x197/0x400
[69396.390401]  [] do_page_fault+0x22/0x30
[69396.390404]  [] page_fault+0x28/0x30
[69396.390424] Code: 00 55 48 89 e5 41 57 41 56 41 55 41 54 49 89 cd 53 48 83 ec 08 0f 1f 44 00 00 49 09 fc 49 89 f7 41 89 d6 48 8b 07 f6 c4 80 75 6c  8b 04 24 f6 c4 40 0f 84 f0 00 00 00 49 8b 04 24 f6 c4 40 0f 
[69396.390427] RIP  [] mem_cgroup_try_charge+0x2f/0x1e0
[69396.390427]  RSP 
[69396.390428] CR2: ffffea020f767740
[69396.390429] ---[ end trace a8c24237c7d97c39 ]---
```

Interestingly `/proc/4088/tasks` has `4168` through `4183`, except `4176`

This issue might be related: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/2445.

Why does it get stuck? What can I do about it?

Answer (score 3):

What causes a page fault in a process is an access to a memory location that isn't currently mapped in RAM. Unless the process is playing dirty tricks with a SIGSEGV handler, there are two reasons why this can happen: it can be an access to an address that isn't mapped in the process, in which case the process will crash (it's a bug), or it can be an access to an address that is mapped but not currently in RAM. The latter is perfectly legitimate: it can be a location in a memory-mapped file that isn't currently in cache, or a location in allocated memory that is currently swapped out.

A page fault means that the process causes a [processor trap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trap_(computing)) (that's the consequence of an access to an unmapped memory address). A trap invokes kernel code, and while this kernel code is running, the process is in state D (uninterruptible sleep).

The page fault caused a “BUG” in the kernel. A BUG is a bug — it shouldn't happen. At this point, the process is in a bad state — the kernel has not been able to make the memory access work. The system is also in a bad state, and depending on the root cause this may or may not be recoverable.

The log message “unable to handle kernel paging request at  ffffea020f767740” indicates what address the process was trying to access. This is a *kernel* paging request, i.e. the bug happened in kernel code to handle the page fault. The address is in the range of kernel addresses. I'm not good enough at analyzing Linux kernel error traces to tell what the problem is. It could be that the kernel has run out of memory for some data structure that's needed to read the data that the process needs. If that's not the problem then see if there are any known bugs in the kernel version you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark, but do you have any memory in NUMA node 0 on that system?  If not, there's a bug you might be hitting.  It looks like maybe the page_cgroup wasn't allocated for that memory location.

Using kernel parameter "cgroup_disable=memory" might work around this bug.